# ASP.net Identity OWIN cookie when user roles change?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, owin, asp.net-roles

I'm just getting started with OWIN and ASP.net Identity. This is how I am signing in my users:

```
ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(
    new Claim[] {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Username),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, user.LastName),
        }, "ApplicationCookie");

foreach(Role role in user.Roles)
{
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role.Name));
}

var owinContext = Request.GetOwinContext();
var authManager = owinContext.Authentication;
authManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = model.RememberMe }, identity);
```

This works and the roles are all wired up correctly. My question is: If the user logs in and has one set of roles, then their roles are updated in the system (perhaps by a system admin), how do you invalidate and re-populate the user's auth cookie?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `Startup.cs` file you can register a `CookieAuthenticationProvider` that will invalidate and regenerate a new cookie for the user after a certain time period

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator
                .OnValidateIdentity<UserManager, ApplicationUser, int>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager)
        }
});
```